# How can i keep the mtime of files and directories when I use rsync or cp? For use in Backup/Incremental Backup

Tags: backup, rsync, cp, timestamps

I have a new NAS box and after looking through numerous backup solutions I've found doing it manually through PuTTy to work the best.

After logging in to the box through PuTTy as root, I first need to copy the entire disk onto a USB HDD (well once every week). I have been using:

```
cp -Rp /data/Backup /media/USB_HDD_3/Backup
```

I have tried with `rysnc -a` instead and I get the similar results in that the files themselves keep the mtime but directories do not.

Then everyday I will be doing an incremental backup. For which I have been building:

```
find . -mtime -2 -exec cp -Rp {} /media/USB_FLASH_1/ \;
```

Again, I've tried substituting `cp - Rp` with `rsync -a` to no avail. I just end up getting the whole of the backup transferred, like it hasn't even looked at the mtime.

I'm rather new to Linux and Unix so most of this I have adapted from things I have found on the net and then tried to slot them together which is probably the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: `rsync -a` should preserve directory times too, it definitely works for me. What version of `rsync` do you have?

Comment: yes that was an error on my behalf, `rsync -a` does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync -a` should work if you simply do:

```
rsync -av /data/Backup /media/USB_HDD_3
```

If it isn't preserving directory timestamps, this is probably a bug in the `rsync` version. As an alternative, you could try GNU `cpio`:

```
find . -mtime -2 -print0 | cpio -0mdp /media/USB_FLASH_1
```

Or more portably (won't handle filenames with newlines):

```
find . -mtime -2 | cpio -mdp /media/USB_FLASH_1
```

Note that `BusyBox` builds often contain stripped down versions of the various tools. Even when built fully it is not completely POSIX compliant, also `cpio` isn't actually in the `POSIX` standard anymore. It is likely that your version of `BusyBox` is built without support for the `-p` option. You would need to use a `cpio` with these options enabled.

I tested the above with GNU `cpio`. I can't find a link to what the old standard for it was, but most likely anything compliant with it will support all these options except `-0`.

Comment: `cpio: invalid option -- 'p'
BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) multi-call binary.

Usage: cpio [-dmvu] [-F FILE] [-H newc] [-tio] [EXTR_FILE]...

Extract or list files from a cpio archive, or
create an archive using file list on stdin

Main operation mode:
        -t      List
        -i      Extract EXTR_FILEs (or all)
        -o      Create (requires -H newc)
        -d      Make leading directories
        -m      Preserve mtime
        -v      Verbose
        -u      Overwrite
        -F FILE Input (-t,-i,-p) or output (-o) file
        -H newc Archive format`

Comment: is the error i get when i run that 2nd piece of code, other than that the 1st error was my own carelessness, it seems that when you copy with windows it "creates" the folder again so my data was incorrect before i even started. I got around this and `rsync -av /data/Backup /media/USB_HDD_3` worked like a charm.

Comment: @user60294, the `cpio` issue is likely because your `BusyBox` has a stripped down version. See my updated answer for more info.

Comment: I see, i'm connecting to a ReadyNAS 102 through PuTTy SSH so i'm not sure how to install a newer/more complete version. If i can.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` needs the update option to avoid transfering all files, `man rsync` give you the manual page and under options you will find,

> ```
>     -u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
>         --inplace               update destination files in-place
> ```

To help understand what it is doing you can use -v option for verbose mode.

> -v, --verbose
>         This  option  increases  the amount of information you are given during the
>         transfer.  By default, rsync works silently. A  single  -v  will  give  you
>         information  about  what files are being transferred and a brief summary at
>         the end. Two -v options will give you information on what files  are  being
>         skipped  and slightly more information at the end. More than two -v options
>         should only be used if you are debugging rsync.
>
> ```
>   Note that the names of the transferred files that are output are done using
>   a default --out-format of "%n%L", which tells you just the name of the file
>   and, if the item is a link, where it points.  At the  single  -v  level  of
>   verbosity,  this  does not mention when a file gets its attributes changed.
>   If you ask for an itemized  list  of  changed  attributes  (either  --item‐
>   ize-changes or adding "%i" to the --out-format setting), the output (on the
>   client) increases to mention all items that are changed in  any  way.   See
>   the --out-format option for more details.
> ```